# Pivot table and merge column with headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, melt

I have DataFrame as below:

```
 Ranges Relative_17-Sep Relative_17-Oct Relative_17-Nov
  <=20%  0.65            0.36            0.29
  >20%   99.35           99.64           99.71
```

I am trying to find a way to convert this to :

```
"Sep17<=20%" "Sep17>20%"   "Oct17<=20%" "Oct17>20%" "Nov17<=20%" "Nov17>20%"
 0.65          99.35        0.36            99.64     0.29        99.71
```

Any help in this.

Thanks

Comment: transposing them might help or extract them using indexing and create a new df as your column names are also not the same, so its better to create a new df

Comment: Pure transpose wont work here, yes I am thinking same as  creating a new DF and loopthrough the old DF to create new, but was hoping someone have a better elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`melt`

```
v = df.melt('Ranges')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    v['value'].values, 
    index=v['variable'].str.split('_').str[-1] + v['Ranges']
).T
```

```
df
   17-Sep<=20%  17-Sep>20%  17-Oct<=20%  17-Oct>20%  17-Nov<=20%  17-Nov>20%
0         0.65       99.35         0.36       99.64         0.29       99.71
```

---

**Option 2**
Modify `df.columns`, followed by a `stack`ing operation.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[-1]
v = df.set_index('Ranges').stack()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    v.values, 
    index=v.index.get_level_values(1) + v.index.get_level_values(0)
).T
```

```
df
   17-Sep<=20%  17-Oct<=20%  17-Nov<=20%  17-Sep>20%  17-Oct>20%  17-Nov>20%
0         0.65         0.36         0.29       99.35       99.64       99.71
```

Comment: Perfect @ColdSpeed, worked like a charm.   And thanks for the correction above

Comment: @RehanAzher No problem!

Comment: But My 17 gone missing . :) I will try to find a way to get it back

Comment: @RehanAzher Ah... split on '_' instead of '-'. I think that will solve it.

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: I Split by `_` instead of `-` and that is still OK. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome solutions

Comment: @Aditya Thanks! Feel free to upvote, I'll return the favour if I see an answer of yours I like ;)

Comment: @Aditya - depending on who you ask... :)

Comment: it's like people who have a lot of repo, they rule, rest follow naively

Comment: @Aditya It is true to an extent, but a ruler does not need to be a tyrant. Also, just keep working hard and you'll be sitting at the top yourself one day. Myself, I am still far from it, but I am getting there slowly.